# Computer science asymptotic terminology

Tags: asymptotics

I have been hearing the phrases quasipolynomial, superpolynomial and subexponential.

I think know what quasipolynomial and subexponential is. I believe these are functions respectively of form $n^{\log^c n}$ and $n^{n^{1/c}}$ for some $c>1$.

What does superpolynomial mean?

Comment: Google "define: superpolynomial" answers this instantly. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Superpolynomial_time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superpolynomial means $n^{\omega(1)}$, that is, growing faster than any polynomial. More clearly, $n^{f(n)}$ for some function $f$ satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) = \infty$.

Comment: So superpoly contains both quasipoly and subexponential?

Comment: @Turbo That's right.